# How do I ensure an excel table that uses a foreign key is reordered fully when the primary table is reordered?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

[Data is in correct order, before first table is rearranged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgiKI.png)

The initial state of the tables, where all of the data is in the correct order. Note how the Fruit names in the second table come straight from the first table using the formula =Table[@Fruit]

[After rearranging the data in the first table, the Cost column is now in the incorrect order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdxUd.png)

After rearranging the first table from Z-A, the Fruit column in both tables is now in the correct order, and the Quantity in the first table is in the correct order. However, the Cost in the second table is now in the incorrect order. This is because it is a manually entered field which isn't bound to the Fruit column

My question is, how can I ensure that all rows in the second column are rearranged when the first table is rearranged?

I think the solution might have something to do with the Data Model however I haven't used it in excel before so I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Hi @Swogget ,, possibly you have not selected both columns Fruit & Cost ,, otherwise SORT will pull correct data,, do it again !!

Comment: @RajeshS Hi Rajesh - if I rearrange table 2, it works perfectly. The problem is, when I rearrange table 1, it only rearranges the Fruit column of the second table, and not the Cost column!

Comment: ,, it's quit natural since you have use formula `=Table1[@Fruit]` in D2 and filled down ,,, so D2:D4 are linked with A2:A4 in Table1,, if U write `=Table1[@Fruit]` in D2 and fill Right the Down ,, excel will pull both Fruit & Qty,, and when U rearrange will do properly.

Comment: ,, but in Table2 , you have Cost is not part of Tabel1,, so that Excel only rearranges the Fruit column in both Tables,,, NO DATA LINK between Col B & E !!

Comment: Great, so I need to add a data link? Do you know how I would do this?

Comment: The important question here is why are you using two tables instead of one?

Comment: @Swogget,, even setting Relationship wouldn't do what you are looking for because Excel doesn't works as other databases,, but give me some time .. I'll soon find solution,,, since it's quit interesting ☺

Comment: @Swogget,,, in Cost column (Second Table) you need to write formula `=IF([@Fruit]="Apple",1,IF([@Fruit]="Bannana",2,3))`, where `[@Fruit]` is 1st column of Second Table,, then after if U SORT, Table 1,,, data will reshuffle is Table 2 also ,, remember Table 2 ,, Fruit Name is linked with it's corresponding column in Table 1. HOPE this HELP you,,, plzz reply ☺

Comment: @FlexYourData Because in the real thing there are about 100 columns, which can nicely be split into 3 seperate purposes. One table is for Sales, another is for Stock and another is for Orders. Splitting the data into different sheets lets me keep the different categories separate.